How to define what type of node when the name has been changed?
For example in this image, This node is labeled as Background but I think this is an emission node from the parameter it has. But in general, if the name has been altered , How can I find out which type of nodes it is ?


If you're connected to the internet you can right click > Online Manual which will open the documentation page for the node. The Background node is particular because it is its own node, although it acts as an Emission node https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.1/render/shader_nodes/shader/background.html?utm_source=blender-4.1.0#bpy-types-shadernodebackground

F2⌦ Del↩ Enter Clear the label. Now you see the original name again.


@andio Apart from the answer given here, your screenshot clearly says you are editing the World shader. It is an Emission shader, but it is called Background and does not exist in the Object shaders. That's why the output is called Background as well, and not Emission like in the regular Emission shader. But they act exactly the same, you can exchange the Background shader for the Emission shader. See this, both nodes are called "Background", but look at the outputs: node labels & outputs

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks for the explanation. This is just simple example I used (world shader). In reality , most of the times when I got project from someone else, a lot of the nodes has been renamed so I'm having problem to find out what nodes it is as i'm trying to learn and find it from the 'add' menu. I hope there's easier way to do it without have to delete the name first , for example, I use Nuke for comp, where I can press 'I' to show the class of the selected Node.

@andio Often the colors of the label bar and the parameters give a hint. Anyway, this answer by Markus solves your problem. The Background shader was probably just an unfortunate choice since it is actually the real name of the shader by Blender itself, but it is also basically just an Emission shader with other names.

This is why you shouldn't rename your nodes. CTRL+J and name a frame if you want to comment what the node does.

@MarkusvonBroady Yep. Even here people sometimes show nodetrees with renamed nodes without explanation as answer to the question of a beginner who might easily be confused. The same with hidden unused sockets. Even with the correct name this sonetimes leads to confusion because a beginner might think he has the wrong node when they have more inputs and/or outputs than shown in the solution.

@GordonBrinkmann Socket hiding is my thing :). I'm aware it's confusing; my defense is, if you don't hide sockets then you're creating an expectation you can't satisfy: suddenly all old setups with noise textures become confusing, because there's no Lacunarity input. I don't think it's false dilemma because as I say, by following a paradigm you're establishing an expectation. I could further argue a handful of missing sockets is more confusing than my severely butchered abominations just as a few deviations from symmetry is more concerning than completely asymmetric design.

In the other direction: you're undermyning great Blender functionality, that an older version can open a project from a newer version, simply ignoring datablocks that it can't support. This decreases technical exclusion of people with older machines but also just removes friction, so you don't have to reopen the project in the oldest possible Blender to share it, and you don't have to update that regularly to open other projects. But if you don't hide lacunarity, you're communicating, that you need this input.

Also you're only really getting confused once by hidden sockets, and it forces you to learn the functionality of hiding sockets/options that you really should learn eventually (just like renaming, I guess; it's just that renaming continues to be confusing and annoying) Finally: hiding unused sockets makes the setup more readable. I could instead slightly blur/darken the unused sockets while taking a screenshot, but that's too much work, while hiding sockets is something I also do for myself. I did get burned a couple times by this: I've hidden a socket that had non-default value set...

However when I share setups, I hide only sockets that you can set to any value without affecting the result. Hiding sockets also allows to move nodes closer and shorten the links, but on the other hand if you change your mind and want to use a socket... Now you need to rearrange the nodes. So as you see I have spent quite some time thinking about this, but if you have more feedback, it's welcome especially as now I think about refreshing my answer here.

I do not doubt the benefits of hiding sockets, especially not if I'm doing projects for myself. I was just talking from experience here reading comments of confused beginners from time to time. Sometimes they are confused when nodes change between versions (which we could do nothing about it) and sometimes it's just people modifying their nodes. Both can result in having different node names and sockets, but if Blender has changed, well that's how it is and we cannot control that. But we can control how much we modify the nodes ourselves and I think less sometimes can be more (for beginners).

I even experience it here that people ask for example "I have no Multiply node in my Blender version", it's a bit unfortunate for beginners that nodes like Math change their names automatically according to the chosen function. Of course I could manually label it back to Math for screenshots here, but that would be much more effort than a lazy guy like me is willing to make, so I usually write in an answer "Math node set to Multiply. But as I said, I don't mind hiding sockets or even renaming for personal use, I just avoid it in solutions here.
